# PHP, Echoing an array into a string of comma seperated values

Tags: php

I have a multi select box i am using to allow users to select multpile users, this is fine but the $_POST output is an array.

How would i get these values to be formatted like so

```
100,200,300,400
```

So i need to echo out the values, add a comma, but dont add the comma for the last value

Any help would be grand.

Cheers

Answer (score 8):

You could use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
return implode(',', $_POST['users']);
```

Comment: You **should** use implode. Implode is quite efficient compared to alternatives (especially when doing it yourself).

Comment: I'm more used to JavaScript than PHP, so I first just tried `echo $_POST['users']`. I was once again reminded that PHP and JavaScript are, in fact, different languages.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array(100, 200, 300, 400); // Or get from your $_POST value or what have you

echo implode(',', $array); // "100,200,300,400"
```