# Comma on array, except last value via PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP, Echoing an array into a string of comma seperated values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857972/php-echoing-an-array-into-a-string-of-comma-seperated-values)

This seems like it should be fairly straight-forward for experienced PHP coders... which I'm not.

This is what I have so far:

```
<?php echo $cfs->get_labels('name'); ?>: <?php $values = $cfs->get('name');
    foreach($values as $value => $label) {echo $value . ', ';}
?>
```

How could I avoid having a comma printed on the last value in something like this?

I've referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376171/removing-last-comma-in-php) and similar, but can't seem to crack it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has been asked before. Try using the search feature next time.

Comment: i did. found plenty, as added in the link in the original post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `echo implode(',', $values);` instead of the foreach loop.

EDIT: whoops, I just noticed you output the keys, so for that you can use:

`echo implode(',', array_keys($values));`

Comment: `<?php echo $cfs->get_labels('name'); ?>: <?php $values = $cfs->get('name');
    echo implode(',', array_keys($values));}
?>` like so then? anyone care to help me spot the syntax error? thanks.

Comment: The syntax error is the last curly bracket

Comment: just caught it as well. thank you @Lex!